# Share one action with two views

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a website which needs a control panel that is used by multiple user types. I've been wondering is it possible to make different views that have different layouts but they are similar in operation use a single action so that I wouldn't need to re-write them again?

For example, both Admin and Supervisors can modify employee details but the admin views have a different layout than the supervisor. I can write different actions for each view, but the code in both actions would be exactly the same as they do the same operation. So can one action be shared with many views ?

Comment: why don't you make a single view and action for both admin and supervisor..just load layout different for admin and supervisor

Comment: @Exception: you mean by if else statements at the top of the view ?

Comment: @Exception: Although this does work, but I can't do this for some reasons in this website

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You certainly can. However, the approach depends on how you determine which layout to present and where that information comes from. The most straight-forward approach is to determine the type of users (Role) and based on the user's role you can render a specific view within the same action method...

```
public ActionResult YOUR_ACTION()
{
    //do your processing
    Role role = GetCurrentUserRole();

    if(role.Name = "Admin")
        return View("ViewForAdmins");
    else if (role.Name = "Supervisor") 
        return View("ViewForSupervisors");
    else 
        return View("EveryoneElseView");    
}
```

Comment: @PierreOverFlow believe me, there's no magic here, it's just plain `MVC` ;)

Comment: One question, I authenticate the user using an ActionFilter, and I get the role in there, is there any way to pass the role to the action which runs after the attribute without using TempData. (Asking just out of curiosity)

Comment: @PierreOverFlow well, it depends, to avoid retrieving the info twice, you could override the `ActionFilter`'s `OnActionExecuting` which runs before the action method is processed. But, I'm guessing the best thing is to use a built-in (or custom) `RoleProvider` and query the `RoleProvider`s methods (for example `IsUserInRole`) as long as you're `RoleProvider` is well-written and doesn't result in a round-trip to a database (or service)....usually, it's just a matter of checking a cookie value

Answer (score -4):

Maybe you could put employee details in a partial view and call RenderAction from main views.